# How to show hide a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On ajax success I have to hide a class and show the different class.
Suppose I have "foo" and "bar" two classes. Now it has "foo" class when my ajax returns success then I want to show the "bar" class.

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"/test/",
        data:{"test_data": my_data},
        success:function(data) {

        },
        dataType:"json"
        // here I want to hide the "foo" class and show the "bar" class.
    });
```

Actually "foo" and "bar" is a class of button. when i click button having "foo" class it should hide and button having "bar" class should be shown. and vice versa

Comment: one element with two classes? or different element with the respective class?

Comment: As you can see from the differences in the given answers, it seems you have to clarify your question. Do you want to *remove/add* classes or *show/hide* elements with the classes `foo` and `bar`. What if an element has both classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mentiond on which element you want to apply this. Anyway this will give you an idea:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"/test/",
    data:{"test_data": my_data},
    success:function(data) {

    },
    dataType:"json"
    complete: function(xhr) {
       // if you want to switch classes on a specific element
       $('element_you_want_to_switch_classes').toggleClass('foo bar');

       // if you want to show/hide different elements
       $('.foo').hide();
       $('.bar').show();
    }
});
```

This will apply the changes after the `ajax request` has completed (regardless if it fails or not). If you just want to apply the changes on success just pack that lines into your `success handler`.

Comment: Actually "foo" and "bar" is a class of button. when i click button having "foo" class it should hide and button having "bar" class should be shown. and vice versa

Comment: Above suggestion only hide the "foo" But couldn't display the "bar"

Comment: @sun-the: if an element with the class of `bar` exists in your markup, this "should" work. Otherwise please provider your exact markup.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".foo").hide();
$(".bar").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the hide and show commands in the success function:

```
....
success:function(data) {
  $(".foo").hide();
  $(".bar").show();
}
```